# implementing LRU in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to implement LRU  Page Replacement. I  was able to get FIFO algorithm to work. But i am not sure how to keep track of the least recently used?

I am reading in a file. its structured like first number is pid(1) and second number is the ref(45) and so forth Like:

```
1 45
1 46
1 45
1 44
2 76
2 75
2 77
2 77
```

So, i am using a class array, and parsing the file  line by line and if its not in the array to put the pid and ref there in that index. If the array is full then go back to the beginning ad start all over.

```
class pagetable
{

public:
int pid;
int ref;
int faults;
pagetable();
};
pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];
```

I am prompting for the number of frames.
I am prompting for the file name and storing it in

```
ifstream inputStream;
```

Then i can call my LFU function and grab each pid and ref to check.

```
int runsimLFU(ifstream &inputStream, pagetable* page, int frames ){

int i =0;
int j=0;
bool flag = false;
int cnt=0;
int index = 0;
int value = 0;

while(1){

  inputStream >> pid;
  inputStream >> ref;

      page[count].pid = pid;
      page[count].ref = ref;
  pagefaults++;
```

Something like this i can keep grabbing each line of the file.

this is how i am searching the array

```
bool findinarray(pagetable* page, int frames, int pid, int ref)
{

 for(int i=0; i < frames+1; i++) {
    if(page[i].pid == pid && page[i].ref == ref)
    {
        return true;

    }
 }
    return false;

 }
```

Two questions

1) I am unsure how to keep track of the LRU. i would imagine a second array and a counter variable but thats as far as i can see what to do.

2) once i know the LRU and when the incoming pid, ref is not in the array i stuff that into the array at index LRU number?

Thank you

Comment: A linked list would probably be easier to use than an array. Either way, all you have to do is take the value you're using and move it to the end (making the front the LRU). If you're using an array, this means you have to use shift everything after the value one space to the left before appending the current item. This is not prohibitively difficult, but does require a bit more book keeping.

Comment: Not sure i understand that. So if i am pointing to the first index(0) in the array and i need to add to the array i shift everything after index 0 to the left and then add to index zero?

Comment: Every time you bring in a new page, append it to the list. Every time you use a resident page, remove it from the list (shifting the remainder in the case of an array (or better yet, a vector)) and replace it at the end. Every time you need to drop a page, take the first entry in the list.

Comment: The standard datastructure for a FIFO is std::deque. Can you use that, and serialize it to a file?

Comment: Isnt there an easier way of keeping track of the LRU as a counter and then stuffing my pid and ref into that? wihout shifting? you are making me more confused.

Comment: Could i use vectors? dont i just need to shift and add to the end?

Comment: Could i use std list or vector?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have two competing needs for an LRU:

- quickly find an entry - suggesting an array lookup, hash table, or binary map as an index, and
- quickly prepend/append/remove an entry - suggesting a linked-list

If you address either requirement separately, you end up with brute-force inefficiencies.  You could coordinate two containers yourself - ideally wrapping them into a LRU class to provide some encapsulation and improve reliability.  Alternatively, boost multi-index containers address such requirements: www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/

Comment: Good response. To add to it: if your LRU cache is relatively small (say, a couple dozen items), then a simple linked list will perform quite well. Larger than that, you need to look into indexing options as the answer describes.

Comment: Could i use vectors? dont i just need to shift and add to the end?

Comment: A "shift" for a vector involves copying other elements out of the way... that can get slow if you have a lot of large elements. As Jim says above - if you have few small elements (and using pointers to elements can help here as the pointers themselves are small) - then a list may suffice.  A vector may also suffice, though in some cases it'll be the worst possible choice as it doesn't allow easy removal mid-container, nor easy insertion at the front, and you still need to iterate over every element to find a value of interest: countering that - vector iteration will outperform list iteration.

Comment: the file  with the data will be quite large. Probobly 1000 items. I dont have much time to work on this. So i want to keep it simple. Im fine with using list if its easiest

Comment: Well, using lists means you have to go through each of the 1000 items every time to see if you have a match in your cache.  You might as well give that a try and profile... if it's too slow you can always add an index afterwards.

Comment: No, im loading the file into a ifstream. see the original post.

Comment: i mean using vectors, or list for the cache. loading the file into ifstream and process that one line at a time. If i remove an item from a list does it dynamically sift the older items up to fill the empty slot?

Comment: A list doesn't move items... it has pointers between them.  It's very efficient to prepend or append items to a list, and very efficient to remove an element you've already found, but to find an element you tend to have to search through the list one by one.  Imagine a telephone book where you weren't allowed to skip ahead based on alphabetic sorting, but had to read every element in turn.  It's ok for a list of 10 friends, but not good for millions.